# PyModbus efficiency with out of order registers and different functions

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I've recently started using PyModbus and have found it very easy to do basic polling with their ModbusTCPClient and read_holding_registers function.

I'm interested now in the best ways to structure a more complex logger - non-consecutive registers, different function codes, different Endian encoding, etc.

For example - to avoid a separate 'read_holding_registers' call for each tag of a device, I have built a function that groups all consecutive tag registers to reduce the number of calls.

I'm planning to implement a similar thing for BinaryPayloadDecoders - group by registers with the same byteorder and wordorder to reduce the number of decoder instances.

```
def polldevicesfast(client, device, taglist):
   #loop through tags, order by address, group consecutive addresses in single reads, merge resulting lists, decode
   orderedtaglist = sorted(taglist, key = lambda i: i['address'])
   callgroups = sorttogroups(orderedtaglist)
   allreturns = []
   results = []

   for acall in callgroups:
       areturn = client.read_holding_registers(acall['start'], (1 + (acall['end'] - acall['start'])), unit=device['device_id'])
       allreturns = allreturns + areturn.registers

   decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(allreturns, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)

   for tag in orderedtaglist:
       results.append({'tagname': tag['name'], 'value': str(tag['autoScaling']['slope'] * mydecoder(tag['dataType'], decoder)), 'unit': tag['unit']})

   client.close()
   return results
```

None of this is extremely complicated - it just seems like there has to already be an accepted standard or template for this somewhere that I can't seem to find in any of their documentation online.

Comment: you can use the same decoder by calling `decoder.reset()` before each decoding action so that you are dealing with the fresh set of registers each time.